# Sharing Data through components

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I want to pass data to my navbar component when I log in to my login component, but my navbar content doesn't update.

My navbar component is in the app-module and my login component is in another module.

I tried use services to share data.

My login component, this component is in the another module

```js
export class LoginComponent {
  userCredentials;
  constructor(
    private readonly _authService: AuthService,
  ) {

  }

  login() {
    this._authService.auth(this.userCredentials)
      .subscribe(
        (response: any) => {

            const dataForm = {
              usuario: response.user,
              rol: this.response.role,
            };
            this._authService.setSession(response);
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  }
}
```

My NavBarComponent, this component is in app-module

```js
export class NavbarComponent  {

  isLogged = false;
  susbscription: Subscription;
  constructor(
    private readonly _authService: AuthService,
  ) {
    this.suscripcion = this._authService
      .changeState$
      .subscribe(
        (isLogged) => {
          this.isLogged = isLogged;

        },
        error => console.log(error)
      );
  }
}
```

My NavBar Html

```html
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <mat-toolbar-row>
      <span>SUPERMERCADO</span>
      <span class="spacer"></span>
      <div *ngIf="!isLogged">
        <button mat-button 
          Login
        </button>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="isLogged">
        <p>Welcome</p>
      </div>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
  </mat-toolbar>
```

My Service, this service is not in the app-module

```js
  @Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  protected url = environment.url;
  protected model = '/user';

  isLogged = false;
  private changeState = new Subject<boolean>();
  changeState$ = this.changeState.asObservable();

  constructor(
    private readonly _router: Router,
    protected readonly httpclient: HttpClient,
  ) {
  }

  setSession(data: any) {
    this.isLogged = true;
    this.changeState.next(this.isLogged);
  }

  auth(dataForm: any): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${this.url}${this.model}/login`;
    return this.httpclient.post(url, dataForm);
  }

}
```

I'm using angular 8.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the LoginComponent part of a lazy loaded Module?

If so you need to add the providedIn: 'root' property to the AuthService:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn : 'root'
})
```

Make sure to remove it from the providers properties of the Module.

If your LoginComponent is not lazy loaded, make sure you only import the AuthService once in AppModule. Otherwise you may end up with multiple instances of AuthService.

If you want AuthService to be part of a module, you can use the forRoot pattern to ensure services are imported only once:

```
@NgModule({
  // declarations, imports and exports only
})
export class SharedModule {

  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
  return { 
    ngModule: SharedModule,
    providers: [// your services]
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [SharedModule.forRoot()]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

If on Angular 8, you can also do:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: SharedModule
})
export class AuthService
```

You want the same instance of AuthService to be available to both AppModule and the Module where your LoginComponent is.

Lastly, if this is not the issue you may have a problem where NavBarComponent subscribes to the changeState$ observable after it emits. In this case you need to change changeState to be a BehaviorSubject, so when NavBarComponent subscribes it receives the last emitted value.

Answer (score 1):

There might be 2 reasons as to why your code does not work as expected.

1. the `changeState` subject emits data **before** the navbar component subscribes to it.
   From what I can understand, when you are on the login page, so the navbar component shouldn't be loaded yet. When you. In your `LoginComponent`, you **first emit** the data, then, when `NavbarComponent` is loaded, you subscribe to the observable that just emitted.
   But, because you use a **Subject**, you will **not get** the **last emitted** value.
   In order to mitigate that, you can use a **BehaviorSubject**, which will **retain** the **last emitted value** for the **new subscribers**.

#### Subject vs BehaviorSubject

```js
const s = new Subject();

s.next('not seen...');
s.next('not seen...');
s.next('not seen...');

s.subscribe(d => console.log('SUBSCRIBER 1: ', d))

// You must first subscribe, as the `Subject` does not holds any values on itself

s.subscribe(d => console.log('SUBSCRIBER 2: ', d))

// `Subscriber 1` will also receive those
s.next('value1 !!');
s.next('value2 !!');

/* 
SUBSCRIBER 1: value1 !!
SUBSCRIBER 2: value1 !!
SUBSCRIBER 1: value2 !!
SUBSCRIBER 2: value2 !!
*/


const bs = new BehaviorSubject(null);

bs.next('not seen');

// It will retain only the last value for the new subscribers
bs.next('hmmm!!')

bs.subscribe(v => console.log('subscriber 1 of BS: ', v))

bs.next('value1!')
bs.subscribe(v => console.log('subscriber 2 of BS: ', v))

/* 
subscriber 1 of BS: hmmm!!
subscriber 1 of BS: value1!
subscriber 2 of BS: value1!
*/
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/catching-errors) is a StackBlitz demo if you want to explore.

So, if you replace your `Subject` with a `BehaviorSubject(null)`, it should work.

2. As you mentioned, `AuthService` is not part of the `AppModule`. There might be a chance of **not getting a singleton**.
   I think you can fix it by adding the `Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` decorator to your `AuthService` class(which will also make the service tree-shakable).

Answer (score 0):

Store Data In Local Storage and access it any where in the components where you want just make one shared service to fetch info and use it.
By {{}} string interpolation 
Service Part

```
getUserInfo() {
   const savedCredentials = localStorage.getItem(credentialsKey);
    return JSON.parse(savedCredentials);
  }
```

Component Part:

```
 this.currentUser = this.authService.getUserInfo();
```

And Access Data Like This :

```
this.currentUser.BusinessDate
```

Answer (score -1):

**From Component**

```
    import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
    import { dataService } from "src/app/service/data.service";
    @Component( {
        selector: 'app-sideWidget',
        templateUrl: './sideWidget.html',
        styleUrls: ['./linked-widget.component.css']
    } )
    export class sideWidget{

    constructor( private LWTableColumnNames: dataService ) { 

    }

    ngOnInit() {
     this.LWTableColumnNames.refLWTableColumnNames =  "patient"; //this line of code will pass the value through data service

    }    
    }
```

**data service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class dataService {
    refLWTableColumnNames: string;//creating an object for the data
}
```

**To Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { dataService } from "src/app/service/data.service";

@Component( {
    selector: 'app-linked-widget',
    templateUrl: './linked-widget.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./linked-widget.component.css']
} )
export class LinkedWidgetComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private LWTableColumnNames: dataService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.LWTableColumnNames.refLWTableColumnNames); // out put will be string "patient"
    }

}
```

[Stackbliz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-br2zzl) in this way you can send values to different sibling components(not only parent child component)